# A chemical compound with these conditions?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, solubility, conductivity

I am searching for a chemical compound which meets these five conditions:

1. slightly soluble in water
2. layered strutcture
3. ionic conductor
4. thermochromism
5. lead must be a part of it.

Comment: I'm not sure is it lead (II) oxide because it has the last three condition. The first two, I am not sure about it

Answer (score 2):

I will satisfy 4 of the five conditions, but you will have to research the fifth. Lead(II) iodide has a layered structure, is slightly soluble in water, is ionic (but only weakly). I hope that this helps.

Comment: Actually, lead(ii) iodide is a bright yellow solid at room temperature, that reversibly becomes brick red by heating. (see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lead(II)_iodide) so it would satisfy all 5 conditions!